# Can OpenAPI specify what the endpoint returns right in the paths responses itself?

Tags: syntax, openapi

Per https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/,
a typical endpoint responses specification is:

```yaml
paths:
  /ping:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
                example: pong
```

The `pong` is put into the `example` section.

Is there any way I can define such fixed response in OpenAPI specification itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit your `string` response to an enum of values

```yaml
paths:
  /ping:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
                enum:
                  - pong
                example: pong
```